# What to use for AttributeName in Xamarin Mac

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to colorize a substring in my NSMutableAttributedString in Xamarin, but it seems to be missing the proper constants,

[image]

What should I put there?

**Update.** This gets closer:

```
var s = new NSMutableAttributedString ("hello");
s.AddAttribute (CTStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor , NSColor.Red, new NSRange (0, 3));
wordLabel.AttributedStringValue = s;
```

and gives

[image]

though the color on screen is still black text!

[image]

**Update2** Maybe CTStringAttributeKey is the wrong one, but there is no NSStringAttributeKey

[image]

Comment: have you tried `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` ?

Comment: In Xamarin.Mac (OSX) I do not find NSForegroundColorAttributeName.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I looked at the API and it seems it's there, just under `NSAttributedString`

[ForegroundColorAttributeName](http://macapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aMonoMac.Foundation.NSAttributedString.ForegroundColorAttributeName)

So use something like:

```
s.AddAttribute(NSAttributedString.ForegroundColorAttributeName, NSColor.Red, new NSRange(0,3));
```

Comment: you are the winner. mil gracias.

Comment: the parameters on the NSRange constructor just result in a crash. I used the constructor with no params to fix this...

Comment: @robringham did you ever find a solution for iOS, it seems that with xamarin mac mobile framework nsattributedstring no longer has the foregroundcolorattributename, and ctstringattributekey does not work

Comment: Looks like it is now "NSStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor"

Answer (score 16):

In case people are wondering what the equivalent is for Xamarin iOS, here it is: The foreground color attribute name can be found here: [UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=P%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor)

Also `NSColor.Red` should be `UIColor.Red`

So adding an attribute should look like:

```
s.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor, UIColor.Red, new NSRange(0,3));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just spent like a full hour trying to change this little bit of text. What a waste of time.

Answer (score 7):

**Important:**

The keys in Xamarin.Mac have changed from `NSAttributedString` to `NSStringAttributeKey` so this:

```
s.AddAttribute(NSAttributedString.ForegroundColorAttributeName, NSColor.Red, new NSRange(0,3));
```

Should be:

```
s.AddAttribute(NSStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColorAttributeName, NSColor.Red, new NSRange(0,3));
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that what was stated above is the correct answer:

```
s.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor, UIColor.Red, new NSRange(0,3));
```

The NSRange value appears to relate to the length of the string.  So if the string is `5` characters long, the NSRange should be `NSRange(0, 5)`.

Comment: This should have been a comment on the answer you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make the above solutions work because it could not convert from `NSMutableAttributedString` to `UIStringAttributes`. So after playing a little bit with the code I got this working solution:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes
{
    ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
};
```

This is for Xamarin.iOS, complementing Mike Richards answer. I've never developed for Xamarin.Mac, so I don't know if it would work there.