# How to change the navigation bar title color on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'd like to know how to change the navigation bar title's color. This is how it should be done in swift:

```c
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes =
                             [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
```

How can I replicate that behavior using Xamarin.iOS?

I tried working with the answers here [What to use for AttributeName in Xamarin Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720067/what-to-use-for-attributename-in-xamarin-mac) but I couldn't make it work because it could not convert from `NSMutableAttributedString` to `UIStringAttributes`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how you do that:

```cs
UINavigationBar.Appearance.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes
{
    ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
};
```

Answer (score 5):

```
void StyleNavBar()
    {
        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes()
        {
            ForegroundColor = UIColor.White,
            Font = UIFont.FromName("overpass-bold", 14)
        }; 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @eestein I'd like to add that **this has to be done in the public override void ViewWillAppear** - I've tried to change styles of the NavigationBar in the *ViewDidAppear* and had many hours of fun, frustration and despair figuring out why something works for others but not for me and if it's not working - then what will :)))